# Kotlin : Create extension function file?plus

Tags: android, file, kotlin, kotlin-extension

I am developing some lib in **Kotlin**, I am not finding this solution,

[image]

How can I resolve this issue, **It's saying that create extension function File?.plus**, 
In java it works fine but in **Kotlin** how to write this code?

Comment: Please not  just copy a screenshot into the issue if possible but provide the sourcecode.

Comment: I think Screen Shot make my issue clear

Comment: @MohitSuthar - but it doesn't encourage people to help.  Please use text for code rather than screenshots.

Comment: ok next time i ll remember, and thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have three options:

1) Avoid that you concat a `File` with a `String` by calling the `toString()` what results in concating two strings.

```
val sdCard = File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/PicTaker/Images")
```

2) Write that extension-function and return a string

```
private operator fun File?.plus(s: String): String {
    return this.toString() + s
}
```

3) Use string template

```
val sdCard = File("${Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()}/PicTaker/Image‌​s")
```

Comment: String template also works. `"${Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()}/PicTaker/Images"`

Comment: @BakaWaii great third option. I add this one in this post. thx

Answer (score 6):

You don't need to invent more code, just change the plus (+) to a comma(,).

```
val sdcard = File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "/PicTaker/Images")
```

Answer (score 3):

Add `toString()`:

```
val sdcard = File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "...")
```

In Kotlin, we can do operator overloading for + and Kotlin compiler thinks you are trying to use the overloaded plus operator for `File?` type. And provides an option to create the extension function to `File?`